# Can I no longer use App Engine default service account as an Email API authorized sender for my Python App Engine project?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a App Engine Python application that I'd like to send an occasional automated email.

In the past, with a different application, I was able to set the default service account (e.g. `my-project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`) as an authorized Email API sender on the App Engine settings page:

- https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings?project=my-project-id

Now, when I add the service account email and push "Save" button, I get a pop-up notification that says "Saving settings..." then nothing.

I got the default service account value from the IAM & Admin page:

- https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=my-project-id

I have even added the App Engine roles to the App Engine default service account member.

**Note:** I was able to make my personal email account which owns the project an authorized sender and successfully send emails. But I would prefer to send API emails with the App Engine service account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I was overcomplicating this. In my older project, I had the project's default App Engine service account added as an authorized sender as described in the question. It seems this is neither necessary or even any longer possible.

To send emails using the App Engine Mail API from an App Engine project account, simply set the sender value in your code to an address formatted like so: `any-name@my-project-id.appspotmail.com`.

For example:

```
mail.send_mail(sender='no-reply@my-project-id.appspotmail.com',
               to='user@example.com',
               subject='App Engine Mail API Test',
               body='Please do not reply.')
```

This is stated correctly in [the App Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/):

> #### Who can send mail
>
> For security purposes, the sender address of a message must be one of the following:
>
> - The Gmail or Google Apps Account of the user who is currently signed in
> - Any email address of the form anything@[APP_NAME].appspotmail.com or anything@[APP_ALIAS].appspotmail.com
> - Any email address listed in the Cloud Platform Console under Email API Authorized Senders